# Jump to a specific time on youtube video (Android)

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I already loaded a video on a mobile phone using YouTubePlayerView. I was wondering if anyone could help me with the code to jump to a specific time (e.g., 2m4sec) on a video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `YouTubePlayer`'s `seekTo` methods to jump a video to a specific time.

```
YouTubePlayer.seekToMillis (int milliSeconds)
```

[**`More about this method`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#seekToMillis(int))

Or:

```
 YouTubePlayer.seekToRelativeMillis (int milliSeconds)
```

[**`More about this method`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#seekRelativeMillis(int))

If you want to start a video right away from a certain time, you can use:

```
YouTubePlayer.loadVideo(String videoId, int timeMillis)
```

[**`More about this method`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: I tried to use loadVideo method to jump to another location with a button press event. however, it shows the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This YouTubePlayer has been released

Comment: It's working now. need to put myYoutubePlayer = null; in the onDestroy() method